# Ubuntu gives message "Welcome to emergency mode !"

Tags: ubuntu, boot

I am using latest Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. For some days after installing system worked fine but after some days it start showing this error.

> Welcome to emergency mode!
>
> After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or ^D to try again to boot into dafault mode.
>
> Press Enter for maintenance
> (or press control-D to continue):

But there is one way using which I can start system. On boot up I go to recovery menu then clean package and then resume the system. It works but , it is time consuming to do after every boot up. Suggest something simple and cleaner to resolve this problem.

Before going into emergency mode it gave message as:

> [12.320307] intel_soc_dts_thermal:request_threaded_irq ret -22

In case anyone interested in seeing log files : http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/644902/error_log.txt

Comment: you might be running out of disk space .. have you checked that aspect ?

Comment: @amisax no not really there is too much space remaining. By the way system has dual boot with windows 8 if this may help in any sort.

Comment: We are not clairvoyant.  We cannot suggest things without knowing why emergency mode is being triggered; and we have no access to that knowledge.  You have a message in front of you telling you to look at the logs, which would provide that knowledge.  You aren't showing the logs in this question, nor indicating that you have even looked at them to see what the fault is.

Comment: @JdeBP I have log file. It consist of 4000 lines what you want should i paste it here?

Comment: before going into emergency mode it gave message as : [12.320307] intel_soc_dts_thermal:request_threaded_irq ret -22

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The **Emergency Mode** sometime means that your file system may be corrupted. In such cases, you will be left out with a prompt to go nowhere.

All you have to do is perform a file system check using,

```
fsck.ext4 /dev/sda3
```

where `sda3` can be your partition and if you are using `ext3` file system, change the command as follows:

```
fsck.ext3 /dev/sda3
```

About the partition number, Linux shows you the partition before arriving at the prompt.

This should solve the problem.

Comment: Check /etc/fstab to see what disks are mounted by default, it will be one of those that need to be checked.

Comment: When I do this it says /dev/sda3 is mounted. Should I umount it first?

Comment: @Lavya Of course. Use `umount`.

Comment: [I am having a similar problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/735793/ubuntu-gives-message-welcome-to-emergency-mode-fsck-just-says-clean), but `fsck` is of no help, as it just says my devices are `clean`.

Answer (score 12):

From my experience, if you have created a new partition or edited existing one, you may get this error. I had the same error some time back. If you happened to be in the the **Emergency Mode** and see that it cannot load some of your drive. It means that some of your device id have been changed. So, you have to update the id accordingly in `/etc/fstab` file. Then do the following steps.

1. Type your root password
2. `cat /etc/fstab`
3. blkid (show the device ids)
4. Now check which which UUID in `/etc/fstab` does not apper in blkid output
5. type `nano /etc/fstab` and Comment out that line (Just put # infront of the line)
6. type `reboot` (Now your problem should be fixed and after logging in successfully, you can add the current UUID in `/etc/fstab` file )

As an example, this is my output of /etc/fstab file, in which I simply commented out the line ( `UUID=C3D1-3CB7  /windows vfat utf8,umask=007,gid=46 0 1`), because the UUID=C3D1-3CB7 has been changed.

[image]

Comment: I had the same issue because I had deleted and reinstalled the EFI partition and after following the steps of this answer I was able to boot normally into Ubuntu.

Comment: I had this problem because I have been auto-mounting an external drive for a while, but recently removed it and still had the entry for it in fstab, once I commented out that entry it booted just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same problem.
Here's a solution that might work:

use Ubuntu Live USB to boot, and open terminal:

```
sudo fsck.ext4 /dev/sda3
```

adding`sudo` because it needs root permission.

(Replace `ext4` with `ext3` if applicable to you)

Cycle through the SDAs by changing the last number in the `sda` to see which file system has problems.

Ex: `sda1`, `sda2`, `sda3`, `sda4`, and so on

As I encountered, the problem might be with the 'home' directory.

Once you run the above command, you'll be prompted to fix the issue right inside the terminal itself.

Keep hitting `y` (for yes) until the end of the fix.

(or you can use -fy for automatically response yes to all.)

Navigate to the `home` folder of your `sda` using your files explorer.

(This will be mounted from the HDD since you are working with a Live USB)

Check inside 'home' if you can see all your files.
If yes, then you're ready to reboot to your system (remove the Live USB).

Comment: Running Kubuntu 20.04.1 dualboot with Windows10, fixing Windows partition led to Kubuntu setup leading in emergency mode, enabled and then disabled "Fast Startup" in Windows, then did this for sda10, and sda9(root-# shell available in maintenance option without LiveCD, right in Kubuntu), home and system partitions, it appears to have worked... it's an old HP-AC026TX  Cheers!

Comment: [I am having a similar problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/735793/ubuntu-gives-message-welcome-to-emergency-mode-fsck-just-says-clean), but `fsck` is of no help, as it just says my devices are `clean`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the `fsck` didn't help. But the problem was that, as a part of experimenting, I had created a virtual partition of a ext3 over the ext4 filesystem and mounted it.

It worked fine. Later had edited the `fstab` to automount that during boot. After the reboot after many days, the system went into emergency mode.

Finally entered the maintenance mode and edited the `fstab` file and rebooted. The system came up. It's a conflict of filesystem for sure.

Answer (score -1):

[image]----Firts of all download Gparted live cd, burn it to cd/dvd or usb card,open terminal then using this command **blkid** or **fdisk -l** to know parts

**fsck -с /dev/mapper/*yourhostname*--vg-var**

### [image: if your /var wan't mount]

or if your /home wan't mount use this command

**fsck -с /dev/mapper/*yourhostname*--vg-home**

etc.
-----------kblprbl312-----------------------------

Comment: Do not paste images. Paste commands in **Code block** instead.